# When I try to split an image into sections to process separately and count the number of white pixels in each I get an error?

Tags: python, ros

I'm not sure how I would go about doing this, here is what I have so far.

```
def camera_callback(self, rgb_msg):
   

    # Check frame counter
    if( self.frame_count % self.frame_skip != 0 ):
        self.frame_count += 1
        return
    self.frame_count = 1
    
    
    # Get the camera image and make a copy
    img = CvBridge().imgmsg_to_cv2(rgb_msg, "bgr8" )
    img_hsv=cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    img_gray=cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    

    hsv_low=np.array([self.H_low,self.S_low,self.V_low], np.uint8)
    hsv_high=np.array([self.H_high,self.S_high,self.V_high], np.uint8)

    mask=cv.inRange(img_hsv, hsv_low, hsv_high)
    res=cv.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

    self.n1=res[0:480,   0:213]
    self.n2=res[0:480, 214:427]
    self.n3=res[0:480, 428:640]

    
    nnz1=cv.countNonZero(self.n1)
    nnz2=cv.countNonzero(self.n2)
    nnz3=cv.countNonzero(self.n3)

    if(nnz1>nnz2 and nnz1>nnz3):
            self.yaw_rate=.5
    elif(nnz2>nnz1 and nnz2>nnz3):
            self.yaw_rate=0
    elif(nnz3>nnz2 and nnz3>nnz1):
            self.yaw_rate=-.5 
    
    self.msg.angular.x=self.yaw_rate
    self.pub_twist.publish(self.msg)

    #print(mask.shape[0]," ",mask.shape[1])

    #cv.imshow("mask",mask)
    #cv.imshow("res", res)
    self.display_image("mask", mask,True)
    self.display_image("result",res, True)
```

The error I get when running it is

> [ERROR] [1656360138.949456]: bad callback: <bound method LineFollowNode.camera_callback of <**main**.LineFollowNode object at 0x7f10c61a7b20>>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
> cb(msg)
> File "/home/student/catkin_ws/src/hw06_freeman/scripts/line_follow.py", line 130, in camera_callback
> nnz1=cv.countNonZero(self.n1)
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) ../modules/core/src/count_non_zero.dispatch.cpp:124: error: (-215:Assertion failed) cn == 1 in function 'countNonZero'

Answer (score 0):

You’re trying to count non-zero pixels on a colored image. You cannot do this as it’s only meant to function with greyscale images. You should be using `img_gray` instead of `img` with `res`